# python can't find numpy

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy

I was trying to follow the instruction from this link :http://www.thisisthegreenroom.com/2011/installing-python-numpy-scipy-matplotlib-and-ipython-on-lion/
However, it seems my python can not find the Numpy, Scipy and everything I install using pip.

Right now, when I type which python, it shows **/usr/local/bin/python**. 
However, when I type

```
  pip install numpy
```

it shows

```
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): numpy in /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python.
```

Thus it seems they are in different directory, and probably I installed `numpy` previously, which makes pip keep telling me they are installed. I wonder is there any way around that ?

update, I have tried to import it.

```
    import numpy
    Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
    ImportError: No module named numpy
```

I have also tried to uninstall the numpy and install it again. However, when I uninstall it. It still gives me error.

```
    applematoMacBook-Air:~ apple$ pip uninstall numpy
    DEPRECATION: Uninstalling a distutils installed project (numpy) has been     deprecated and will be removed in a future version. This is due to the fact that uninstalling a distutils project will only partially uninstall the project.
    Uninstalling numpy-1.8.0rc1:
/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/numpy-1.8.0rc1-py2.7.egg-info
    Proceed (y/n)? y
    Exception:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip-6.1.1-py2.7.egg/pip/basecommand.py", line 246, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip-6.1.1-py2.7.egg/pip/commands/uninstall.py", line 70, in run
    requirement_set.uninstall(auto_confirm=options.yes)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip-6.1.1-py2.7.egg/pip/req/req_set.py", line 274, in uninstall
    req.uninstall(auto_confirm=auto_confirm)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip-6.1.1-py2.7.egg/pip/req/req_install.py", line 730, in uninstall
  paths_to_remove.remove(auto_confirm)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip-6.1.1-py2.7.egg/pip/req/req_uninstall.py", line 126, in remove
    renames(path, new_path)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip-6.1.1-py2.7.egg/pip/utils/__init__.py", line 292, in renames
  shutil.move(old, new)
    File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/shutil.py", line 302, in move
    os.unlink(src)
  OSError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/numpy-1.8.0rc1-py2.7.egg-info'
```

Comment: for starters.. what Unix Version are you running Python on?

Comment: @OluDoug Sorry. I am running Python on the Mac OS 10.10

Comment: Why do you think your python is not able to find it? How you tried to import it?

Comment: Yes, I have tried that. it gives me back this :Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named numpy

Comment: what does your sys.path return..?

Comment: What You need is path to numpy in PYTHONPATH environment variable, not in PATH

Comment: I am sorry. Would it be possible to expand a little more details on how to do it?

Comment: "which python" in terminal will show you which version of python you use by default. Could be different than one that you run.

Comment: @DennisSakva Yes. That is what I think where is the problem. But I don't know how to fix it.....

Comment: @Zhekai
http://www.scicoder.org/2011/09/setting-the-default-version-of-python-on-a-mac/

Comment: @DennisSakva Thanks! I followed the instruction. Here is when things go strange. I followed the instruction, and choose the version 2.7. When I type /usr/bin/python it shows up the python version 2.7.6. And I am able to import numpy. However, when I quit. And just type "python" in my command line. It shows up the python version 2.7.9 and I can't import numpy. Am I still using the wrong version of python?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like the version of `pip` you are using is using the default mac system-wide python interpreter `/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python` instead of the one installed in `/usr/local/bin`.

I've pretty much experienced the same issues until I started using [homebrew](http://brew.sh/). I'd recommend to have a look at this page on [brew and python](http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/starting/install/osx/). You'd might need to remove `pip` and reinstall it from `brew`. Btw, using `brew`, there's no need for `sudo`.

Comment: As I followed the link, I  used the homebrew to install the python. However, in the link I posted, he mentioned add export "PATH=/usr/local/bin:$PATH" to the .bash_profile . The link you just provided, says add "export PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:$PATH " to .profile. I tried your ways, when I re-install python in homebrew, it indicates "Warning: python-2.7.9 already installed, it's just not linked" . So do you think is there a way to fix this?

Comment: I think I fixed the issue... Even though I don't know exactly how or why. I basically uninstall the python from homebrew, and reinstall it, and install the pip again. Everything seems work file right now. Thank you.

Comment: The issue was the `pip` executable you've used earlier used the system-wide python interpreter. This means that all packages installed this way end up in the system's `site-packages` folder. If you fire up the *brewed* interpreter (also with its own site-packages folder), it does not have these packages available (although you could indicate that in the PYTHONPATH).

By removing and reinstalling pip, the new pip version just uses the brewed python and its associated site-packages folder.

Comment: After brew install python2 , I can use python2 myapp.py but python command is still calling the system-wide installed python.

Answer (score 0):

try: `pip uninstall numpy`

and then: `pip install numpy`

...and try it with sudo:
`sudo pip install numpy`

Comment: I have tried your way. It still gives me error. I update on the up

Answer (score 0):

first, you should use `pip list` to check out have you installed numpy .

if you already installed, check out your program IDE whether the `pycharm`, and check the pycharm interpreter does the local interpreter or virtual interpreter. if the interpreter is virtual, you should change to local. if it works, you can create the new project with select the local interpreter.

more detail: https://www.jianshu.com/p/9c3507cca2b9

in my problem, i can't update scikit-learn with `pip install -U scikit-learn`, and occur the problem

`Cannot uninstall 'scikit-learn'. It is a distutils installed project and thus we cannot accurately determine which files belong to it which would lead to only a partial uninstall.`

it occured in your error too. so, i find your problem.

and i try the commod  `pip install -U --ignore-installed scikit-learn`, and it solve my problem.